# Use Diff to Exclude Quote Symbol - "

Tags: diff

An Abnormal one. 
In simple i have two Source folders.
Both have different code sets i want to compare. 
But there is one Symbol that will show multiple differences that i want to ignore.

Its between single and double quotes ' - "

i.e.

```
$BlankValue="TEST";
$BLANKValue='TEST';
```

Is there anyway i can use Diff to ignore the above for example.

I was using Diff with Sed, But when doing the expression i got Stuck. 
Unable to use Double quotes inside single. 
How can i go about getting around this.

Answer (score 5):

assuming file1 has `$BlankValue="TEST";` and file2 has `$BLANKValue='TEST';` and you want to ignore both case and quote differences, use

```
diff <(tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' < file1) <(tr "a-z'" "A-Z\"" < file2)
```

if you do not want to ignore case, and ignore only quotes, use

```
diff file1 <(tr "'" "\"" < file2)
```

Comment: or, more conventionally

     `$ tr "'" '"' < file2 | diff file1 -`

Comment: thanks, didn't know one could mix quotes like that with `tr` :)

Comment: @Sundeep, it is a shell feature. The " and ' have different meanings, here they are just used to (easily) quote each other.